# Load 3D models in openGLES IOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es

How we can render maya's 3D model in openGLES (iOS) ? 
Is there any tutorial or sample code to do so ?? 

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can output a COLLADA model from your Maya model, then you could use [cocos3D](http://brenwill.com/2011/cocos3d-importing-converting-collada-to-pod/) to load and display it.

Also, have a look at [this post](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-game-development/4696-working-maya-models-iphone.html) explaining ho to work directly with Maya models on iOS.

Comment: I want to do this in openGLES without using cocos3D